# Allow users to sell in-app products in my Android app

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am building a marketplace Android App to sell digital goods as well codes (coupons) and I like to allow my app users (using Google Sign Up) to sell their products within my app using in app purchasing.
I will transfer the money they earned manually (via PayPal).

Example:
The app is about hotel coupon codes. App users are able to buy a coupon code as well sell a coupon code.

Is it possible to let app user create in-app products within my app?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to the doc on in app billing for android.
http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/index.html

What kind of products you don't say, however, I will leave you with this:

```
"You can use in-app billing to sell only digital content. You cannot use in-app billing to     sell physical goods, personal services, or anything that requires physical delivery."
```

Comment: You might notice apps like Amazon do this. These apps have jumped all the loops and trials to obtain a special permission from Google to do so.